# Django 2.0 path error ?: (2_0.W001) has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to create the back-end code for a music application on my website.

I have created the correct view in my views.py file (in the correct directory) as shown below:

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Details for Album ID:" + str(album_id) + "</h1>")
```

However, when creating the URL or path for this (shown below)

```
#/music/71/ (pk)
path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9])/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

I am experiencing a warning on my terminal stating:

> ```
> ?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^(?P<album_id>[0-9])/$'
> [name='detail'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^',
> or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to
> django.urls.path().
> ```

And whenever the `/music/` (for which the path works) is followed by a number, such as `/music/1` (which is what I want to be able to do) the page cannot be found and the terminal gives the above warning.

Comment: I think you either want to use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path) or don't use regex in the url pattern (`path('music/<int:album_id>/', ....)`.

Comment: You are mixing new and old urls syntax. Either change url to `path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')` or use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

Comment: It would be so nice if django would tell what to use instead.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The new [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) syntax in Django 2.0 does not use regular expressions. You want something like:

```
path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

If you want to use a regular expression, you can use [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re_path).

```
re_path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9])/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

The old [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#url) still works and is now an alias to `re_path`, but it is likely to be deprecated in future.

```
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9])/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, I figured I was using url() instead of path() and trying to merge the two together without realising which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

Just to add to what @alasdair mentioned, I added re_path as part of the include and it works fine. Here is an example

Add re_path to your import (for django 2.0)

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', home, name='home'),

]
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using 're_path' you can also use ''(empty string) as the first argument of your path(). I have used it and it worked for me.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 5):

**`url()`** is deprecated in newer version of django. So instead of **`url()`** use **`re_path()`** in your urls file as follows:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9])/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't work add this code to yoursite\urls.py inside urlpatterns:

```
path('music/<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an empty string '' instead of '/' or r'^$'. It works like a charm. Code is as below:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In django 2.0 version primary key write this way...

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.course_list),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.course_detail),
]
```