# This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path()

Tags: python, django, database

So hello guys, I am new to this django and i have encountered this type of error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TERUs.png)

while this if my url.py

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import path
from Project.views import viewAppointment, addDiagnosis
from . import views
app_name = "Project"
   urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index , name='index'),
      path('counter', views.counter, name='counter'),
      path('Register', views.Register, name= 'Register'),
      path('login', views.login, name='login'),
      path('logout', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
      path('post/<str:pk>', views.post, name = 'post'),
      path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
      path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0- 
     100]+)', viewAppointment, 
      name='appointment'),
      path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0- 
       100]+)/AddDiagnonsis', 
      addDiagnosis, 
      name='AddDiagnosis')
      ]
```

meanwhile this is my views.py

```
def viewAppointment(request, appointment_id):
    appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(id=appointment_id)

    return render(request, 'appointment_form.html', 
    {'Appointment': appointment})

def addDiagnosis(request):
    return True
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: helllo Karl so as you can see in the picture i have that kind of error which i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 2.0 path error ?: (2\_0.W001) has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661536/django-2-0-path-error-2-0-w001-has-a-route-that-contains-p-begins-wit)

Comment: please provide models.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are getting system error so do this:**

change this only and try

```
from django.urls import re_path

    urlpatterns = [
               re_path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0-100]+)',viewAppointment, name='appointment'),
               re_path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0-100]+)/AddDiagnonsis', addDiagnosis,name='AddDiagnosis')
        ]
```

Comment: it should be "from django.urls import re_path"

Comment: @london_utku It was an typo mistake thank you for to observe this